# Netbeans: jDialog not showing content?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdialog

For my uni assignment I am doing a healthcare register, and I was thinking off login in -> looking at past vaccines(pop, jdialog) -> register new vaccine(pop up, jdialog), but for some reason my jdialog isn't showing the content only the top right corner(Mac) with the Close, minimize function. Any help?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   jDialog1.setVisible(true);

}                                        

private void KodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                    

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jDialog2.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Do you actually add anything to the dialog? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why the dialog isnt showing up completely. However, from my understanding, the "JComponent" (JDialog) pops up ( as you stated). In general, i would ask myself:

1. Has "jDialog2" been instanciated
2. Have the components been added to the JDialog before setting the Dialog   to visible(true)?
3. you can try using the method "setSize" to specify the width and height of the dialog, however there would obviously be an automatic size-adjustment if you added the components.
4. Maybe you have to change it somewhere else, since it looks like youre using a Swing/Awt-Gui-Builder-Tool

Comment: Yes I am using the GUI-Builder-tool. I am still new to programming so I am all for learning! Can you specify the 2 first options you mentioned? Do you mean that I will have to write a code for it to show the content?

Comment: Hey! Well GUI-Builder-Tools for Java provide a good way to get started with GUI's right ;). Since they mostly use the GroupLayout, which is part of the normal Java Runtime, you shouldnt be afraid that your GUI wont work after a "eclipse-plugin-update" (but your option to reuse the dnd-functionality maybe..)
To 1: There has to be some kind of code like : JDialog jDialog2 = new JDialog()
To 2: When you drag a component into your JDialog, your Gui-Builder will probably write something like jDialog2.add(..) or jDialog2.addComponent(...) .

Comment: Also keep in mind that some Swing-Container-Elements require some more definition like **setting a layout** first before adding the components. Without knowing your specific code-syntax, i would suggest adding a layout to your JDialog first, then add the component(s).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I found a solution and that was to use the setSize function, and now everything is showing. Thank you for your time though!